# php require_once ("database connection file") is not working when running a query from an other include_once file

Tags: php, mysql

on my main page I have my

```
//connection to database
require_once('inc/conn_db.in');
```

I also have a file that

```
// Device Search::
require_once('inc/ProductSearch.php');
```

queries made from the main page work fine.
The problem lies when I run queries from the second require_once file ('inc/ProductSearch.php')

I could be completely wrong but I would think that the database connection is open, and that I should be able to query while the main page is open.

the only way I am able to run the query is when I include the  require_once('inc/conn_db.in'); 
in the second file.

Is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong

content of the conn_db.in::::

```
############################################################
// Create Script to Connection to the Database

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "$$$$$", "$$$$$$");
// Check if the connection to the database Server can be created
    if (!$conn) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
// Check if it can find the Database on the Database Server 
    if (!mysql_select_db("$$$$$$")) {
        echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
```

#

any help or directions are appreciated

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Where did you get this code? Is it from a legacy application or is it intended for something new? `.in` should be `.inc` by PHP convention as "included file".

Comment: @tadman It should be `.php` actually, since it contains, well, PHP. Naming the file with `.inc` only can lead to the web server showing the content of the file if not configured properly.

Comment: @rlanvin That's why you should never, **ever** store `.inc` files in the public web root. Period. The same holds true for `.php` which is why your public web footprint should be as tiny and harmless as possible. Most web frameworks have a minimal `index.php` stub and everything else is external to that, included as necessary. Worst case scenario you see the boilerplate hook code, no big deal.

Comment: @tadman Of course but in real life mistake do happen and a file can end up being publicly accessible. So why would you even take the risk? It's simply bad practice to name a file anything else than `.php`. You can use `.inc.php` if it makes you happier.

Comment: @rlanvin That's why, say it with me, you **do not** store `.inc` files in the public web root. Mistakes happen. When they do you want them to expose as little information as possible. `.inc.php` is less than ideal because a properly configured web server will actually try and execute those if they're called. That could lead to all kinds of disasters. `drop_database.inc.php` may not be something you want people to arbitrarily trigger.

Comment: @tadman In this example, I'd choose risking the "disaster" of creating an useless connection over risking to publicly display the database credentials.

Comment: @rlanvin If you store `.inc` or `.php` files with sensitive code or credentials in your public web root you're playing with fire. You will get burned.

Comment: @tadman You seem a bit obsessed with the public web root folder. Of couse the code should be outside, but it's not the point. In real life it's not always possible and you don't always have a choice... or somebody screws up the server config at some point and your files outside the document root becomes accessible. I have seem both situations happen (more than once, sadly). Having the files named `.php` will mitigate the disaster, because the content of the file is less likely to be displayed. But anyway, this is not the answer to OP's problem so I won't insist.

Comment: @rlanvin Being "obsessed" with best practices and avoiding security holes is perhaps not a bad thing.

Comment: ok I get that PDO is the way to go. but my question was about the require_once function.

queries made from the main page work fine. The problem lies when I run queries from the second require_once file ('inc/ProductSearch.php')

It does run the query unless I add a new connection to the Database